# Add php and composer alias on QNAP Startup

Tags: php, shell, composer-php, alias, qnap

I came across a couple of issues with my QNAP NAS TS-251+ whilst developing a new project these are:

1) There is no php alias and when I add one via command line it is removed on NAS Restart.

2) A similar thing happens for [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) except on restart it removes [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) as well from the system.

How can I stop this from happening or get around it so that when my NAS restarts the php and composer alias are already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding a new script that runs when my NAS starts up. QNAP have provided some basic instructions on how to add a startup script on their wiki page under [Running Your Own Application at Startup](https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Running_Your_Own_Application_at_Startup). However I added a couple more steps t

These steps are fairly basic:

1. Login to your NAS Server via SSH.
2. Run the following command `mount $(/sbin/hal_app --get_boot_pd port_id=0)6 /tmp/config` (Running `ls /tmp/config` will give you something similar to below)

[image: <code>mount /sbin/hal_app</code> command output]

3. Run `vi /tmp/config/autorun.sh` this will allow you to edit/create a file called autorun.sh **
4. For me I wanted to keep this file as simple as possible so I didn't have to change it much, so the script is just called from with this Shell Script. So add the following to `autorun.sh`.

autorun.sh code example:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # autorun script for Turbo NAS
 /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/autorun/autorun_startup.sh start
 exit 0
```

You will notice a path of `/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/autorun/` this is where my new script that I want to run is contained, you don't have to have yours here if you don't want to however I know the script will not be removed if placed here. `autorun_startup.sh` this is the name of the script I want to be running, and `start` is the command in the script I want to be running.

5. Run `chmod +x /tmp/config/autorun.sh` to make sure that `autorun.sh` is actually runnable.
6. Save the file and run `umount /tmp/config` (Important).
7. Navigate to the folder you have put in the `autorun.sh` (script in my case `/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/autorun/`) and create any folders along the way that you need.
8. Create your new shell file using `vi` and call it whatever you want (Again in my case it is called `autorun_startup.sh`) and add your script to the file. The script I added is below but you can add whatever you want to you startup script.

autorun_startup.sh code example:

```
#!/bin/sh

RETVAL=0
QPKG_NAME="autorun"
APACHE_ROOT=`/sbin/getcfg SHARE_DEF defWeb -d Qweb -f 
/etc/config/def_share.info`
QPKG_DIR=$(/sbin/getcfg $QPKG_NAME Install_Path -f /etc/config/qpkg.conf)

addPHPAlias() {
    /bin/cat /etc/profile | /bin/grep "php" | /bin/grep "/usr/local/apache/bin/php" 1>>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && /bin/echo "alias php='/usr/local/apache/bin/php'" >> /etc/profile
}

addComposerAlias() {
    /bin/cat /etc/profile | /bin/grep "composer" | /bin/grep "/usr/local/bin/composer" 1>>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && /bin/echo "alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'" >> /etc/profile
}

addPHPComposerAlias() {
    /bin/cat /etc/profile | /bin/grep "php-composer" | /bin/grep "/usr/local/apache/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer" 1>>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && /bin/echo "alias php-composer='php /usr/local/bin/composer'" >> /etc/profile
}

download_composer() {
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/local/apache/bin/php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        /bin/echo "Enable PHP alias..."
            /sbin/log_tool -t 0 -a "Enable PHP alias..."
        addPHPAlias

        /bin/echo "Downloading Composer..."
        /sbin/log_tool -t 0 -a "Downloading Composer..."
        download_composer

        /bin/echo "Enable composer alias..."
        /sbin/log_tool -t 0 -a "Enable composer alias..."
        addComposerAlias

        /bin/echo "Adding php composer alias..."
        /sbin/log_tool -t 0 -a "Adding php composer alias..."
        addPHPComposerAlias

        /bin/echo "Use it: php-composer"
        /sbin/log_tool -t 0 -a "Use it: php-composer"

        ;;
stop)
        ;;

restart)
        ;;
*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1

esac

exit $RETVAL
```

9. Run `chmod +x /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/autorun/autorun_startup.sh` to make sure your script is runnable.
10. Restart your NAS System to make sure the script has been run. After restart for my script I just did `php -version` via terminal to make sure that the php alias worked and it did.

> (*) With steps 3 and 8 you can either do this via something like WinSCP or continue doing it via command line (SSH). For me I chose to do it via WinSCP but here is the command still for SSH

I am fairly new to server related stuff so if anyone has a better way cool.